# what's the principle of debugging react-native remotely in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, react-native

I know that chrome `devtool` could be used as an open debugger frontend, with receiving debug info by a websocket from debugger host and displaying them such as source file and console log, it also supply a flow-control GUI for single step task as long as the host supports.

but according to the `ReactNative`'s remote debug page:

> React Native JS code runs as a web worker inside this tab.

it seems that the chrome is not only a frontend but also executes the code being debugged? so my question is:

1.how can the device-dependent code be executed in chrome?

2.will the device also execute code ? if it is, what's the relationship between it and chrome? if not, how does the app run in device?

Comment: [https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html)

Comment: hi @SathishSundharam ,I have read that doc, but it's only a usage guide, it doesn't explain my questions.

Comment: I don't have much detail for you, but I can confirm I've observed different behaviour in Android debug vs Android release in a couple instances. The first that comes to mind is `'someString'.startsWith()` as seen by this issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11370

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.how can the device-dependent code be executed in chrome?**

> In case of Chrome debugging mode, the JavaScript code runs within Chrome itself (instead of the JavaScriptCore on the device) and communicates with native code via WebSocket. Here, it will use the V8 engine. This allows us to see a lot of information on the Chrome debugging tools like network requests, console logs, etc.

[Source: React Native Made Easy](https://www.reactnative.guide/3-react-native-internals/3.1-react-native-internals.html)

Note that Chrome's V8 Javascript Engine is not the only React Native can use, you could debug in Safari as well and the code would run on Safari's JavascriptCore. See [this for more](https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging.html#safari-developer-tools)

**2.will the device also execute code ? if it is, what's the relationship between it and chrome? if not, how does the app run in device?**

No, the JS code executes only in one place, either the browser's javascript engine if you are debugging, **thus communicating with the device via Websockets**, or the JavascriptCore of the device if running without debugging.